# Django Activity Stream with Multiple Databases

Tags: django, activity-streams, django-activity-stream

[Django Activity Stream](https://django-activity-stream.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) uses the concept of Generic Foreign Keys. However, [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/multi-db/#limitations-of-multiple-databases) doesn’t currently provide any support for foreign key or many-to-many relationships spanning multiple databases.

So, is it possible to use Django Activity Stream where we are using 2 databases - one has users info and the other has content (which if changes, the users should be notified) ?

Comment: I suppose that your other database for content is nosql(non-rel) database. Just like open-edx. So, django-activity-stream might not work here. You can call APIs from other databse with a secure secret key validation on both end.